# Making jquery ignore the placeholder text while checking if input is a null or not?

Tags: jquery

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="addcredits">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username"><br /><br />
    <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="credits amount"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addcredits").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#name");
        var amount = $("#amount");
        var submit = $("#amount");
        var error = $("#error");

        if (username.val() != null && amount.val() != null) {
            console.log("hi");
        } else {

            error.html("One of the fields were empty..");
            error.fadeIn("fast");

            setTimeout(function() {
                error.fadeOut("fast");
            }, 5000);
        }

    });
});
```

username and amount fields are always not nulll, because of the placeholder text.
Is there a way to make jquery ignore placeholder?

Comment: Field values are never null regardless of whether there's a placeholder or not. You need to compare against an empty string, not null.

Comment: You are assigning $("#amount") twice. And you don't do anything with your submit variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val()` always returns a string, so check for empty strings. jQuery has a `delay()` method for animations, so no need for timeouts, and if you're only use the selectors once, there's no point in caching them :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addcredits").om('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if ( $("#name").val().length && $("#amount").val().length ) {
            console.log("hi");
        } else {
            $("#error").html("One of the fields were empty..");
                       .fadeIn("fast");
                       .delay(5000)
                       .fadeOut("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Although most of your answers are correct, I think that @Jony Kale asked is another thing. He is **always** getting the placeholder value. To avoid checking placeholder value in an input html element, try this:

```
(element.val() != $(element).attr("placeholder")
```

Then, you can use it in a function that checks if the input is empty or not:

```
function isEmpty(element) {
    return ((element.val() != $(element).attr("placeholder")) && (element.val().length > 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing it with null try to compare if it is an empty string or not

```
username.val().length;
```

or

```
username.val() != "";
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/5nkG3/1/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addcredits").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#name");
        var amount = $("#amount");
        var submit = $("#amount");
        var error = $("#error");

        if (username.val().length > 0 && amount.val().length > 0) {
            console.log("hi");
        } else {

            error.html("One of the fields were empty..");
            error.fadeIn("fast");

            setTimeout(function () {
                error.fadeOut("fast");
            }, 5000);
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="addcredits">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="credits amount">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <div id="error"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (username.val().length!=0 && amount.val().length != 0) {
    console.log("hi");
} else {
    console.log("working");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not check the value with `null`, here it will not be `null` it is `blank` here,
so `username.val()` is enough to check.
And for `placeholder` you can check it by using `attr` like,

`username.val()!=username.attr('placeholder')`

Full **code**

```
 if (username.val()  && username.val()!=username.attr('placeholder')
  && amount.val()  && amount.val()!=amount.attr('placeholder')) {
        console.log("hi");
 }
```